# Matlab - How to detect time on analog clock image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm new to Matlab and image-processing and I got the following exercise I cant deal with: I have to segment the hands on the picture linked below and get the time by the position of clock hands.

http://imageshack.us/a/img600/9025/faliora.jpg

Could anybody give me a clue how to do that? maybe some example code

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The simplest way is to detect clock's arrows (for example by Hough transform) and by their width & angles calculate time. Widths of arrows are just semi-widths of corresponding peaks on hough-image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform): Hough transform will help you to detect all lines on image.

Every point in Hough space is one line on an image. The stronger peak on Hough image - the longer line on original image.

Also Hough image can tell you about widths of lines: wide line is a set of parallel lines close to each other, so on Hough space R-coordinate of peak corresponding to a wide line will be broaden proportionally to its width, also angular coordinate will be broaden, but not so noticeably.